# How do i use Loop for my Chinese Zodiac Sign Java Project

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I started learning java and im a total newbie. I decided to make Chinese Zodiac signs for my project but the requirements are: 
 we should use arrays and loops

i already figured out how to use arrays for this project but i dont know how to insert the loops. i tried googling for examples but all are switch and if else statements. hope you guys could help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You create array. Populate it. Then use for loop starting at 0 because arrays start at 0 and go until you are at last element of array. In my example I have array with 3 elements so my elements will be at 0,1,2 positions. `zodiacs.length` will give me 3 so I start counting from 0 to 2 including 2

**Using for loop**

```
String zodiacs[]  =new String[3]; 
    zodiacs[0] = "Aries";
    zodiacs[1] = "Whatever";
    zodiacs[2] = "something";


    for(int i = 0 ; i < zodiacs.length ; i++) {
        System.out.println(zodiacs[i]);
    }
```

**Using while loop**

```
String zodiacs[]  =new String[3]; 
zodiacs[0] = "Aries";
zodiacs[1] = "Whatever";
zodiacs[2] = "something";


int i = 0;

while(i < zodiacs.length){
    System.out.println(zodiacs[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Since you are not allowed to use HashMap, idea is to create 2 arrays: one for years and one for zodiac signs. Each zodiac sign should be at same index as it's representative year. example "Whatever" is in 1992 so at zodiacs[0] should be "Whatever" and in years 1992 shoud be at years[0]

```
String zodiacs[]  =new String[3];
    int years[]  =new int[3];

    zodiacs[0] = "Aries";
    zodiacs[1] = "Whatever";
    zodiacs[2] = "something";

    years[0] = 1991;
    years[1] = 1992;
    years[2] = 1993;

    int yearUserWasBorn = 1992;

    int i = 0;
    int zodiacIndexForUserYear = -1;

    while(i < years.length){

      if(years[i] == yearUserWasBorn){
          zodiacIndexForUserYear = i;
          break;
      }

      i++;
    }

    if(zodiacIndexForUserYear == -1){
        System.out.println("Sorry we couldn't find you zodiac based on you year");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Zodiac is : " + zodiacs[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that i was making a Chinese Zodiac. where do  i insert the formula to get the equivalent zodiac for the year that the user inputs?

Comment: @Red I updated my answer you can check it out

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. but putting all the equivalent years for the chinese zodiacs would be very long. that ranges from year 1000 to year 9999. thanks.

Comment: @Red well.. I don't know hot to help you then, because this question cannot be answered I'll flag it